# How to accumulate test scores?

Tags: java

This is what I currently have:

```
private void EnterBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (isValidData())
    {
         int count = 0;
         int score = Integer.parseInt(TestScoreTF.getText());
         int sumScore = 0;
         int sumScores = sumScore += score;
         count ++;
         NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
         NumberOfScoresTF.setText(nf.format(count));
         int avgScores = sumScores/count;

         AverageScoresTF.setText(nf.format(avgScores));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a `sumScore` variable? It serves no purpose.

Comment: This whole situation `int sumScores = sumScore += score;` may be valid code, but it's very unusual

Answer (score 2):

All of the values will get lost as soon as the method exits, because the variables are *local* to the method. If you need to "remember" values between method invocations, then declare `sumScore` and `count` as attributes in the class.